# SSH Clone - Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I can't get my SSH configuration to correctly work with BitBucket.
I set up anything like SSH keys in my account settings and repo settings.
I set up my git configuration.
I removed my *known_hosts* file.

I always get the same error:

> git pull --tags origin main
> Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

That's the `ssh -v git@bitbucket.org` output:

```
Removed due security reasons. Sorry.
```

Comment: You might want to try having `git clone` run `ssh -v`, rather than plain `ssh`, to observe the connection and session. But it looks like `bitbucket.org` is just closing the connection without saying why. Note that you can configure the ssh command to run with `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` or `core.sshCommand`.